# R data frame from data stored in a variable length concatenated string

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains a number of features against an id delimited by |:

```
df = data.frame(id = c("1","2","3"), 
features = c("1|2|3","4|5","6|7")
)
df
```

My goal is to have a column for each feature and an indicator of its presence for an id e.g.

id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
1   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
2   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
3   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

The features are stored in a different table so complete list of possible features is available but it would be better if I could generate this dynamically.

My first attempt was to use a horribly slow for loop with grepl() populate a pre created matrix 'm' e.g.

```
  for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  print(i)
  if(grepl("1\\|", df$feature[i])) {m[i,1] <- 1}
  if(grepl("2\\|", df$feature[i])) {m[i,2] <- 1}
  if(grepl("3\\|", df$feature[i])) {m[i,3] <- 1}
  if(grepl("4\\|", df$feature[i])) {m[i,4] <- 1}
  if(grepl("5\\|", df$feature[i])) {m[i,5] <- 1}
  if(grepl("6\\|", df$feature[i])) {m[i,6] <- 1}
  if(grepl("7\\|", df$feature[i])) {m[i,7] <- 1}
}
```

Ignoring the fact that my regex will fall over when the features get into the teens. This is terribly slow on the ~400,000 rows I need to run this over. Additionally I need to create an if() for every single id instead of this happening dynamically.

Is there any way to do this more succinctly with dynamic column generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural object to return is a matrix. Here is a way to do this in base R.

```
# split features column by pipe symbol  and subset result, dropping pipes
temp <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$features), split="|"), function(i) i[i != "|"])
# use %in% to return logical vector of desired length, convert to integer and rbind list
myMat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(temp, function(i) as.integer(1:7 %in% i)))
# add id as row names 
rownames(myMat) <- df$id
```

This returns

```
myMat
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
2    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
3    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

If you really want a data.frame, you can use

```
temp <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$features), split="|"), function(i) i[i != "|"])
myDf <- cbind(id=df$id, data.frame(do.call(rbind,
                                          lapply(temp, function(i) as.integer(1:7 %in% i)))))
```

which returns

```
myDf
  df$id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
1     1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
2     2  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
3     3  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks lmo and thepule ended up combining the two answers as the actual feature range is 1....300 and solution split the feature string into individual integers i.e. 24 becomes "2","4".

Answer (score 0):

A different implementation of @Imo solution using `stringr` and `dplyr` for a more compact notation, and adaptable for features ranging from 1 to whatever number:

```
# Split the feature column
temp <- str_split(df$features, "\\|") 

# Find the maximum feature
maximum <- as.numeric(max(do.call(rbind, temp), na.rm = T))

# Crate the final data frame
lapply(temp, function(i) as.integer(1:maximum %in% i)) %>%
    do.call(rbind,.) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%
    cbind(df, .)
```

Which produces:

```
  id features V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1  1    1|2|3  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  2      4|5  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
3  3      6|7  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
```